# "Do not ask again"-popup in liferay

Tags: jsp, popup, liferay, portlet, alloy-ui

I see myself faced with a probably easy task and I feel like walking in the wrong direction. I need to have a popup when a user visits the default landing page. This popup should display an external webpage (some login-stuff we cannot circumvent with single sign on) in an iframe or so. Since only some users have to use this dialog, we want to give the opportunity to not having this popup again (by cookie or DB, it is ok if resetting this option has to be done manually by admins). So basically we need a "Do not ask again"-popup with an iframe.

We decided to put a MVC portlet on the landing-page that has no size; only the popup. What I have is an AlloyUI popup with iframe, a checkbox and the feeling that this is the wrong way as I cannot get information from that checkbox when the popup closes.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://alloy.liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />

<aui:script>

    AUI().ready('aui-dialog', 'aui-overlay-manager', 'dd-constrain', 'console',
        function(A) {

            var bodyNode = A.Node.create('<div><iframe src="http://www.dummysite.com"></iframe> </div>');
            var footerNode = A.Node.create('<input name="donotaskagain" type="checkbox"></input> <label for="donotaskagain">Do not ask again</label>');

            var dialog = new A.Dialog({
                title: 'DISPLAY CONTENT',
                centered: true,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                width: 510,
                height: 430,
                bodyContent: bodyNode,
                footerContent: footerNode
            });
            dialog.render();
        }
    );
</aui:script>
```

I hope you can help me with this. All background information on how to proper use JSP, AlloyUI and Java in that context would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We circumvented the problem by introducing a form for the footer of the popup that will be submitted when the user hits a save button. It is not optimal as the page needs to be refreshed, but since the popup does not occur then anymore, it is acceptable. Maybe someone else could post a post a solution using AJAX so the behavior of this is more smooth.

First we have the view.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://alloy.liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />

<portlet:actionURL name="storeDoNotAskAgain" var="storeDoNotAskAgainURL"></portlet:actionURL>

<!-- Check here whether or not the popup should be shown. We used JSP tags (an "if" around the script) 
    and a JAVA helper class to access the Expandobridge to get a variable from the Liferay DB 
    to decide whether or not the user had chosen not to display the popup again.
<!--  Create Alloy UI dialog with iframe pointing to the specified site as a body and form as footer.
    The form can be submitted to store the "do not ask again"-checkbox value in DB. 
    It is connected with an action from of the portlet. -->
<aui:script>

    AUI().ready('aui-dialog', 'aui-overlay-manager', 'dd-constrain',
        function(A) {

            var bodyNode = A.Node.create('<div><iframe src="http://www.dummysite.com"> </iframe> </div>');
            var footerNode = A.Node.create('<form action="<%= storeDoNotAskAgainURL%>" method="post"><input type="submit" value="Save" class="submit"><input name="donotaskagain" type="checkbox"></input> <label for="donotaskagain">Do not ask again.</label></form>');

            var dialog = new A.Dialog({
                title: "Title",
                bodyContent: bodyNode,
                footerContent: footerNode
            });
            dialog.render();
        }
    );
</aui:script>
```

Then we created a new portlet main class to handle the store-action referenced by the form.

```
package com.example.portlet;

import ...

public class MyPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

    @ProcessAction(name = "storeDoNotAskAgain")
    public void storeDoNotAskAgain(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) throws Exception {
        boolean val = ParamUtil.getBoolean(request, "donotaskagain", false);
        // store boolean in db or a file
    }
}
```

Pro forma: You need to adjust the portlet.xml to point the portlet main class to the new portlet class

```
<portlet-class>com.example.portlet.MyPortlet</portlet-class>
```